# Directory API returns 403 forbidden

Tags: google-api, service-accounts, google-directory-api, google-workspace

i'm trying to use the **directory API by using a service account that I've enabled his [Domain-wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#next_steps) and off course also authorized this service from the admin console using the json file credetials downloaded when creating the service account.**
I've also **enabled the admin sdk** from the google developers console
and i'm using the **[googleapi](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/#create-a-service-client)** library
in order to get access token for the service account

```
import * as  google from 'googleapis';//google sdk for api+Oauth
//creating JWT auth client for service account:

const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  client_email,
  null,
  private_key,
  scope, // (included the   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user" scope)
  null,
);


      let tokens
      jwtClient.authorize( (err, tokens)=> {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        } else {
          tokens = tokens
        }
        // Make an authorized request to list of domain users.

        let url = `https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=mydomain`;
        let headers = {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${tokens.access_token}`
        }

        request.get({
          url: url,
          json: true,
          headers: headers,
        }, (err, res, body: {}) => {
          this.handleResponse(err, res, body, resolve, reject);
        });
      });

    })
  }
```

**the tokens are retrived succefully** but when sending the users list request i'm receiving 403 "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
on the other hand when using the google explorer api with the same params it work's

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't provide a `subject` when constructing the `JWT` object (in the line after `scope,` in your code). You should provide the email address of an admin there, so that you get a token impersonating that admin. Otherwise, you're acting as the service account itself, that doesn't have access to your domain's directory (and can never have access - that's why you must impersonate an admin).